# How to narrow down a generic in Typescipt and coerce the generic param to a concrete value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type Fruits = {
    apple: { color: string},
    mango: {sweet: string},
    error: {no: boolean}
}
type FruitNames = keyof Fruits;

function doSomething<T extends FruitNames>(fruit: Fruits[T], name: T) {

    if (name === 'apple') {
        console.log(fruit.color)
                    // Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Fruits[T]'
    }
}
```

How can I get the correct type here? [TS Playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAM5QLxQN4CgoFQCGYYANhAFw5QDGA9mfXNasHEgHYDmAvgDT5CAWyI961bKgDuECMFbsufQYSgQ4cZpM4SoAI3qMIY3rjOhIsRCgByRYRHRYA1hBD0AZteRoA3Li4ngictMBI9JxQACb0AMr0jsAAFsoAPAAq6gAewBCc0ejwvvaOqAB8ABSeNgo+KKgA2hkAuvxQnA5UUBkAlDhCBINQSN6VnY6YGFgA5CTkEDP9eGpqDJyoxgB0TNzVtVsMTHC9w2a8QA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the generic function shape, you can still narrow `fruit` and `name`:

```
function doSomething<T extends FruitNames>(
    fruit: Fruits[T] & Fruits[keyof Fruits], name: T) {
    if ("color" in fruit) {
        console.log(fruit.color) // works now
    }

    const n: FruitNames = name
    if (n === "apple") {
        n // n is narrowed to "apple"
    }
}
```

- `Fruits[keyof Fruits]` intersection will expose `fruit` as union type,  which can be narrowed via control flow
- See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) for the limitation, that generics extending unions cannot be narrowed. As a workaround assign `name` to a new local variable, that has the generic base constraint as type.

[Here is a playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAM5QLxQN4CgoFQCGYYANhAFw5QDGA9mfXNasHEgHYDmUAvgBp8hALZEe9atiioA7hAjBW7Lr0HCCEOHGZSonSVABG9RhHH9cfXKEixEKAHJEREdFgDWEEPQBm95DQAblxcXwROWmAkek4oABN6AGV6V2AAC1UAHgAVKAgAD2AITnj0eEDnV1QAPgAKDShfByUAlFQAbRyAXSgAMja0Dq8ffwr27oF9FyooHIBKHEakfzqAIgYmODWoLiaWxbxCY7pY1DMAOiZuOubAi83mecbrRoZONn1qceAqt0xpq5lqs4hgwVA1iRyBA1odGsc4gB6RH6XboSGkChrF5WIA)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to tell TS that there is a relationship between the `fruit` and `name` parameters, that if `name` is `T` then `fruit` is of type `Fruits[T]`. Unfortunately TS isn't intelligent enough to work that out when they are two different parameters.

Structuring your data as a [tagged union](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/tagged-union-types-in-typescript) however *will* work:

```
type Fruit =
    { name: 'apple'; color: string } |
    { name: 'mango'; sweet: string } |
    { name: 'error'; no: boolean }


function doSomething(fruit: Fruit) {
    if (fruit.name === 'apple') {
        console.log(fruit.color) // property access is ok 
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXgFBW1A3lAOwEMBbCALigHIiwwAbCKgbigGMB7ejuSgZ2BwkBAOZQAvlAA%20WHPmJlKVEkVEcWUPgHcIEYP0HCxkmTjyFSFahDhweGgh0oAjDlwiqJGbwDMEBNmAkDgIoABMOAGUOMmAACyMACh9EFEp4ZGAASjxZbCQfKGTU4AA6BWg0KupaBiYc3DyzdhC%20d1LuEWLM0s5uOCym8QxxIA)

Comment: In the original question code, TS is intelligent enough to work that out on the call site, but not inside the function body. Any idea why?

Comment: Typescript just doesn't support the conditional type narrowing on one variable having an effect on any other variable, even if they happen to be related. The compiler can't sort that out. At the call site, you must fulfill the requirement of the function signature, and each argument is something specific. (If you pass in an apple, the name is "apple", you must also pass in an apple). This is much easy for the compiler to enforce because you are passing in a known type. But in the function, you have to handle the generic case where all values could be any allowed possibility.

Comment: @Ankeet Mani if my answer helped could you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

*As I was typing this, @Aron popped in with an answer that I think is better!  Definitely a lot less code.  But I'll post this anyways as an alternative approach.*

This is a tricky setup because typescript treats the two variables `fruit` and `name` separately, so the information about one won't narrow down the other.  If instead they are both part of the same typed object, then you can make use of a user-defined typeguard to narrow both simultaneously.

```
interface Props<T extends keyof Fruits> {
    name: T;
    fruit: Fruits[T];
}
```

This typeguard asserts that if `true`, we know that `props` is "apple" props aka `Props<"apple">`.

```
function isApple(props: Props<FruitNames>): props is Props<"apple"> {
    return props.name === "apple";
}
```

But you don't need a specific function for each case because you can do this:

```
function isFruitType<T extends FruitNames>(props: Props<FruitNames>, name: T): props is Props<T> {
    return props.name === name;
}
```

Now when you use conditionals you will get the proper typings

```
function doSomethingProps<T extends keyof Fruits>(props: Props<T>) {

    if ( isApple( props ) ) {
        console.log( props.fruit.color ); // ok
        console.log( props.fruit.sweet ); // error
    }

    if (isFruitType(props, "mango")) {
        console.log( props.fruit.color ); // error
        console.log( props.fruit.sweet ); // ok
    }
}
```

In order to do this, I have changed the signature of your function.  But you can delegate it like so in order to get back your original signature with separate props:

```
function doSomething<T extends FruitNames>(fruit: Fruits[T], name: T) {
    return doSomethingProps({
        fruit,
        name
    });
}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAM5QLxQN4CgoFQCGYYANhAFw5QDGA9mfXNasHEgHYDmAvgDT5CAWyI961bKgDuECMFbsufQYSgQ4cZpM4SoAI3qMIY3rjOhIsRCgByRYRHRYA1hBD0AZteRoA3Li4XMAankS00AAKWmCoADwAKuoAHiGcACbobh7e8L6oAHw4QgScDlRQCQFqnjYKPiioANoJALoBZrieCJy0wEj0nFBIqACCpBQAFGAxqNTR9LFxeXblhQCU1DOL6CNQC0sARCTkEIdFeGpw8ghwQ9uxAHRljpgYWMcTZx2B3b39g2GqBWwAS4AgiRSaUyDWA9kchWms3ms2WdXhTgK-CgLwqCU2UAeu3QB3iCQuJSg12AtyGuLeWCJz3KPy6PT6AyG6XoAGV6I5gAALZSkyEQVIQDJZdxeWGIokonaJArrYqUpDeSZA8anLVEqCq1WXNSEBicVDGR5Mbh62aPWq%20R4MJhwA1%20KAAeg9UHoLkpajNFooVvoNsJdodKEeMjkwDdnu9Gi0cEpnTUGqgkxGILBkCRO2xh1E4kO6yN-tNgyDEBDYaZkeATsYzHjXvUmmYFYIgct1ttO3tdWjsnkre9vtT5l%207IBXN5-Pkwp4YolUthGMRDeoIOabWxuOo%20OKVxudyg3L5AqX3FJk2NJqgDdUD5x5VT6w6QA)